# Lottery Transparency

Tags: lottery

Let's say the [Mega Millions](https://www.megamillions.com) jackpot carry over from the last drawing was $500M (this is the full one-time cash payment that would have been made if there had been a jackpot winner) and $600M of tickets (each ticket costs $2) get sold for the next drawing.
(I wish these numbers were more transparent too, since all ticket purchases are probably already logged in a real-time database on the internet, but this is not my focus in this question.)

Assume someone hits the jackpot now and takes the one-time cash payment.  I know it's more likely to be a tie among many people, but that probably does not effect this calculation, so let me keep it simple.

How much of the available $1100M would get paid out?  Ignore taxes (or we can say that taxes do get paid out, to the government).

I tried to find this online (it seems some other lotteries pay out roughly 50% of revenue, from which my answer would be $500M + $300M = $800M), but Mega Millions is surprisingly not transparent.  I know that transparency gets a little difficult when jackpot carry-over and overhead scaling are considered, but is there really no official formula?  Could government officials just arbitrarily say, "Let's only pay out 10% this time since the jackpot is already big and since we promised to double teacher salary"?

Comment: The calculation of the jackpot is based on an annuity payout, lump sum would be about half the jackpot. Is that what you're asking? Also, the lottery is not run by the government. At least not directly.

Comment: @littleadv No, I understand how annuity or lump-sum can be calculated from the other. I am interested in how much the lottery keeps for itself vs what it pays out (just like people ask about casino slot machine payout percentage).

Comment: Questions about gambling or wagering are considered off-topic here. See https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea seems to me like the question isn't really about the gambling. It's asking for Lotto's gross margin, basically. Which is not personal finance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prizes are 50% of sales, and the prize pool allocations are set:

[image]

Lotteries are well-regulated but are at the state-level. For example, here's a 10 page document about Mega Millions in Colorado:  [RULE 14.C COLORADO LOTTERY MULTI-STATE JACKPOT GAME, “MEGA MILLIONS GAME®"](https://static.coloradolottery.com/media/filer_public/26/2f/262feb46-6929-4707-969a-5d2b210b4d90/rule_14c_-_mega_millions.pdf)

They cover roll-over:

> If the Grand Prize is not won in a drawing, the prize money allocated for the Grand Prize shall rollover and be added to the Grand Prize pool for the following drawing.

State lotteries are also subjected to financial and compliance audits, for example:
[COLORADO LOTTERY FINANCIAL AND COMPLIANCE AUDIT - June 30, 2021 and 2020](https://leg.colorado.gov/sites/default/files/documents/audits/osa_co_department_of_revenue_state_lottery_division_2021_financial_statements_-_final.pdf)

Not a guarantee that fraud can't exist in a system, but a high level of transparency that helps people trust that the games are fairly run.

Regarding your example, if $500M were carried over and there were $600M in new ticket sales, then the jackpot pool would be 500M + (600M * .376509) = 725.9M. They display estimated jackpots because the vast majority of sales happen day of the drawing.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  One minor detail that bothers me is that they can't be sure of those percentages; e.g., the total payout from second prize (matching 5 of the 6 balls) alone is a random variable, so I assume 3.96595% is really an average "expected" payout.  But, we can just say everything is clearly regulated to have a 50% expected payout.  That would be very easy to state, so I wish they would put that on the lottery's main website also.  By the way, your answer differs from my guessed $800M just because I was totaling all prizes.

Comment: @bobuhito They address that by reserve accounts:  "If the total of the original MEGA MILLIONS set prizes and the Megaplier prize amounts awarded in a drawing exceeds the percentage of the prize pools allocated to the set prizes, then the amount needed to fund the Set Prizes (including the Megaplier prize amounts) awarded can be drawn from the Prize Pool Accounts and Prize Reserve Accounts or become pari-mutuel prizes as determined by the PRODUCT GROUP."  Pari-mutuel is like the jackpot, split among winners.

Comment: The smaller prize payouts are also, in Mega Millions, the responsibility of the individual states.  California's lottery regulations, for instance, require pari-mutuel, so the non-jackpot prizes are variable.